# How to verify peer authenticity (certificate) in WebRTC?

Tags: objective-c, encryption, cryptography, webrtc, dtls

By WebRTC standard all connections should be encrypted via DTLS. This is great. However, unless application verifies authenticity of the peer, the connection is vulnerable to man in the middle (MITM) attack.

The question is how to do this with libWebRTC (http://www.webrtc.org/native-code) specifically in Objective C interface. Ideally, I would like to be able to specify my own certificate for WebRTC connection. In this case I will be able to verify it through my application-specific secure channel. If this is not possible, then what is the suggested approach? I will be grateful for any hints.

Comment: This question seems a bit broad to me, you may want to show what you've tried. Still, I don't know why it received so little attention. I changed the man-in-the-middle tag to cryptography as man-in-the-middle only has a few followers. Use popular tags! (I don't know nothing about this library, so I cannot answer myself)

Answer (score 1):

The WebRTC specification does not include the signaling layer, i.e., how the fingerprints, ICE candidates, etc are exchanged between peers. This means that in almost all WebRTC applications, there's a signaling socket to rapidly signal the connection with a service which exchanges the information between two peers.

Instead of supplying your own certificates or fingerprints, what you want to do is authenticate the signaling over which those are sent.

Your signaling server effectively *is* the man-in-the-middle, especially in cases of using an MCU or SFU. It should verify the identity of clients exchanging signaling information, and ensure the signaling information is exchanged between mutually agreeing peers (i.e., calling one another by address, or joining a common "room").

So the answer is: use secure websockets, and authenticate clients sending/receiving WebRTC offer/answer information. If you do that, there's no risk of man-in-the-middle attacks, beyond the risk of any other HTTPS+WSS application.